# How do I do an action every time a new file is loaded in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()

Tags: c#, winforms

To clarify the title, whenever a file is loaded while using the DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() method. When I searched on Google or anything you want, I always find

```
var files = directory.GetFiles() //Loads all files in memory then they use it in a foreach loop, which is useless
foreach (var file in files)
{
    progressBar1.Value += (int)Math.Floor(1 / files.Length);
}
```

but as you can see in the comment I added, the method loads all in the memory then they use a for loop but it is useless because it already did the longest action.

**Why I want to do that?**: Simply because I want to show the user where the program is at for loading files in a large folder.

I tried to find alternate methods but I don't find any. Yes, it is short for what I tried.

Tell me if I need to edit anything, but most importantly, ask me specifically what I tried because I can't remember everything I exactly tried.

Comment: If someone gave you a jar of marbles would you know how many are in the jar without first counting them? Probably not. Likewise, how do you propose that a computer should know how many files exist in an particular directory without first querying to find out? If you don't know how many there are, you can't possibly know how long it will take.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. I thought about it and I no longer load all the files, I just put the files, and the folder itself without loading each files in each folders inside of the same folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-7.0) instead of `GetFiles`. Then you are not loading them all into memory before you start processing them but one after the other.

Quote from docs:

> The `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows: When you use `EnumerateFiles`, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned. When you use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, `EnumerateFiles` can be more efficient.

But in my opinion your progressbar is useless anyway, the longest action is where you process the files. So that is where a progressbar would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it and you're right. The progress bar is useless but I didn't know that there is a more efficient way to do this. I changed how my program works, so now it doesn't load everything in a folder, it just loads files and just the folder, not everything inside of it. Thanks